# VBA code when refering a SubReport from a Main Report in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am  setting an instruction (VBA) in  **On Load Event**   on a  report in MS Access.
When I open the report,the code works perfect.
But when i try to embeded the report as a subreport on a main report, the code doesnt work.
I think  the problem is that I should be referering the field different(Me.Service1...), since I am trying to call the field now  from a main report, but i havent found the right syntaxis. 
This is the code i wanna embeed on my main report:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()


If Me.Service1 = "Scanmachine" Then
Me.Vessel.Visible = True
Me.Label400.Visible = True
Else
Me.Vessel.Visible = False
Me.Label400.Visible = False
End If


End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: so am I right in thinking that `service1`, `vessel` and `label400` are all on the main report?

Comment: no, they are fields from the subreport only...

Comment: oh ok, I will edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you need to change the relative reference of your sub report controls. Over the course of my Access database development work, I have used this [Access MVPs resource](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm), even bookmarked the webpage (though it uses forms, the same naming setup applies to reports).

Consider the following, adjusting names accordingly and run this on the main report's `OnOpen()` event:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

   If Me![subreportcontrolname].Report!Service1 = "Scanmachine" Then 
       Me![subreportcontrolname].Report!Vessel.Visible = True 
       Me![subreportcontrolname].Report!Label400.Visible = True 
   Else 
       Me![subreportcontrolname].Report!Vessel.Visible = False 
       Me![subreportcontrolname].Report!Label400.Visible = False 
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: IT worked with the code, i wrote it as you said and it worked, thanks for the help. I have seen that table you linked, but i could understood it before.. now I get it. Thanks for the help :)